# setting boundary for tree (data structure)

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm

We are dealing with a project which involves some work on coding base on tree/forest algorithms.

Consider in a 2D graphical environment you are drawing a set of lines AB, BC and CD. These three line segments are connected at B and C points.

[image]

Let's imagine, AB and BC are horizontal but CD is vertical.

Now if I rotate AB 90 degree (counter clockwise) the rest of lines must follow the same degree of rotation. Now in our code AB and BC work fine but when it comes to CD it doesn't follow the rest of lines.

So expecting something as:

[image]

Seems we need a recursive method however, not sure what kind of boundaries we have to consider here because CD might end up to get another line at its end e.g. DE  so adding a boolean flag as "bLastLine" won't help here.

SO how can we find out when an line is ended? in fact I need to know how to assign boundary to a tree.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I might have an answer for you, but I would like to see your expected output first. Can you post a second picture showing the rotated output?

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing how your image is a tree data structure. However, you probably don't need a boolean bLastLine. Children.Count == 0 should be enough if you model your data right.

Comment: expecting output is uploaded in my question. Please see above.

Comment: In addition, I'm not seeing how you plan to draw this and how it pertains to wpf. If you are using DataTemplating in WPF, you could use a HierarchicalDataTemplate. However, if you are planning on interactivity, you may want to flatten that collection in the ViewModel, and rebuild your tree later.

Comment: To add one more question about the expected output, where is the origin in each drawing?

Comment: everything starts with a line. One segment line. If you mean as far as coordination then it can be any where on canvas. I'm not sure if this is what you asked.

Comment: To me it sounds like you might be transforming one or some of your points twice.   When transforming, make sure transform points, and not the lines that reference those points.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I'm going out on a limb here. You have nodes (A,B,C,D) and you have lines segments between them. This could be considered as a Graph(V,E), which may suit you better than a tree.

Now for WPF:

Your Vertex class would have an Edges property of type ObservableCollection
Your Vertex class would have a Point property of type Point.
Your Edge class would have an Vertices property of type ObservableCollection, which will be 2.

Your ViewModel would contain a list of all edges and all vertices, which you will bind to.

Your View will DataTemplate your edge as a Line. Within the DataTemplate, you would drill into both vertices on the edge to get either end of your line. (You could use a small Ellipse for your Vertex.)

Now for the Math:

```
private static Point[] Translate(Point[] points, double tX, double tY)
{
    return points.Select(p => new Point(p.X + tX, p.Y + tY)).ToArray();
}

private static Point[] Rotate(Point[] points, double theta)
{
    return points.Select(p =>
                        new Point(p.X * Math.Cos(theta) - p.Y * Math.Sin(theta),
                                    p.X * Math.Sin(theta) + p.Y * Math.Cos(theta)))
                    .ToArray();
}

public Point[] RotatePointsAroundPoint(Point[] points, Point origin, double theta)
{
    var tPoints = Translate(points, -origin.X, -origin.Y);
    tPoints = Rotate(tPoints, theta);
    return Translate(tPoints, origin.X, origin.Y);
}

public void RotateGraph(Vertex[] vertices, Point origin, double theta)
{
    var points = vertices.Select(v => v.Point).ToArray();

    var tPoints = RotatePointsAroundPoint(points, origin, theta);

    for(var i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        vertices[i].Point = tPoints[i]; 
}
```

With this, you simply need to determine the origin and the degree of rotation. Once you call the setter on `Vertex.Point`, the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event will update the `View`.